# iPhone stuck on Connect to iTunes

Tags: itunes, restore, ios, iphone

My iPhone is stuck on Connect to iTunes Screen (support.apple.com/iphone/restore iTunes logo and up arrow with lightning cable)
I have Tried :-

1. Connecting it to iTunes and Updating, It updates Successfully.But on the same screen again [image: Update Successfull]
2. Restoring, It restores successfully.But on the same screen again[image: Restore Successfull]
3. Tried Recovery Mode Screen Method and DFU method
4. Tried Closing and Restarting iTunes
5. Tried Deleting 'iPhone Software Update' folder in iTunes and Re-Downloding Updates

Nothing Works...
Any Help will be appreciated

Comment: Could you be restoring an unsigned iOS version? https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/288013/iphone-has-been-updated-successfully-but-why-is-it-still-stuck-on-connect-to-itu

Comment: No I was in iOS 11 DP 2
You cant directly downgrade from that to iOS 10
The correct way was to downgrade from iOS 11 DP2 -> DP1 -> iOS 10